# $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&c&-1\\ 1-c&-a&0\\ 5&3&b\end{pmatrix}$ has an eigenvector $(-1,1,-1)'$, and $|A|=0$, can we find $a,b,c$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&c&-1\\ 1-c&-a&0\\ 5&3&b\end{pmatrix}$ has an eigenvector $(-1,1,-1)'$, and $|A|=0$, can we find $a,b,c$?

By $Ax=tx$ for some $t$, we see $c=1+t-a, b=t-2$ (with the other equality superfluous), and then
$0=|A|=t^3-(2a+1)t^2+(3a+1)t-6a$. Oh my god, we can not do anymore.

Comment: I don't think that the other equality is superfluous--I think it's an independent equation. You have $c = -1+a-t$, $c = 1+a+t$, and $b = -2+t$ from the eigenvector given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\det(A)=0$, then we have
$$-ba^{2}-5a+(c-1)(bc+3)=0,\quad (1)$$
Since $(-1,1-1)$ is an eigenvector for some eigenvalue $k$ of $A$ we have
$$-a+c+k=-1,\quad (2)$$
$$-a+c-k=1,\quad (3)$$
$$-b+k=2,\quad (4)$$

Solving the non-linear system with equations $(1),(2),(3)$ and $(4)$ with Mathematica we have one solution
$$(a,b,c,k)=(3,-3,3,-1).$$
It works, since

- $\det(A)=\det\begin{pmatrix}3&3&-1\\ 1-3&-3&0\\ 5&3&-3\end{pmatrix}=0$.
- $Av=\begin{pmatrix}3&3&-1\\ 1-3&-3&0\\ 5&3&-3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-1\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix}=-1\begin{pmatrix} -1\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix}=kv$.

So *a priori* with that information we can find the values $a,b,c$. Of course, it would be interesting to be able to avoid using the software.

Comment: (A) OP assumed that the other Equation is useless , Actually , It is not useless. (B) We do not require Mathematica : (B1) We can see that (2)-(3) gives $2k=-2$ or $k=-1$ , (B2) With that , (4) gives $-b-1=2$ or $b=-3$ , (B3) More-over , (2) gives $a=c$. (C) Determinant gives a Quadratic Equation which is easy to solve (D) We will get $a=c=3$ (E) Hence we get $(a,b,c,k)=(3,-3,3,-1)$ , without software.

Comment: @Prem: Thank you, I had access to the software when I was writing the answer, so it seemed appropriate to use it. Of course, all the equations are importants in order to answer the problem. However, I meant a not so "mechanized" in order to avoid the non-linear system. Although the way that I wrote itself is elementary, in some sense.